# Powerpoint customize Ribbon - Color Picker

Tags: powerpoint, ribbon, powerpoint-2010

I was wondering whether and how it is possible to change the colors available for customizing Ribbons: [image: Screenshot]. I am using PowerPoint 2010.

As I result, I want a color palette with my own colors on my ribbon.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards,
Tobias

Comment: I'm assuming some add-in has installed these options; most likely you can figure out how it's done by renaming the PPAM to PPAM.ZIP and looking at the XML within.